# comparing unicode input with database string

Tags: php, mysql, html, utf-8, encode

I have been searching over and over in stackover but does not find solution for my problem.
I need to compare the string from user input with the existing string in the mysql database.
The string stored in the database as this: 
`xu&#7845;t kh&#7849;u` which means: "xuất khẩu" :)

The string user input from text box is: "xuất khẩu"

but when I try to compare the 2 string, mb_encode, htmlentities, etc.. but in no way it says the string matched!

The database use utf-8 general ci, and website display utf8 font correctly.

Can any one give me the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you're comparing to use:

```
html_entity_decode($mysqlValue, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // Compare with the unprocessed user input.
```

(This will decode the DB values from the HTML entities into the special characters.)

Or:

```
htmlentities($userInput, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // Compare with the unprocessed DB value.
```

(This will encode the user's input from a string containing special characters into a string containing the HTML entities.)

The text in the DB are HTML entities, so I would look for a solution based on that. I doubt UTF-8 encoding is the problem, but it's good to specify into the function just in case.

Comment: I try your solution and it not works. $foo=$row[$column]; // get from database
$bar=$value; // user input
$foo=html_entity_decode($foo, "ENT_QUOTES", "UTF-8");

Comment: @gaixixon You'll want to remove the quotes around ENT_QUOTES since it is a constant. If you've written your code this way as in your comment (and assuming $foo and $bar are containing the correct DB / user input values) you can now test using conditional if ($foo == $bar) {echo 'same';} else {echo 'not same';}

Comment: I think i've found the problem. before passing the variable to PHP, via ajax call, i use `$("#checkname").load("modules/utils/checkname.php?tb=product&column=product_name&value="+encodeURI(this.value));` so when I check the string WITH spacebar and NON-unicode character, the code works.  But when comparing string with spacebars AND with unicode character, the code not works.  Can you give me solution for this?

Comment: Aha, OK that makes sense. In that case, you'll want to decode the user input inside PHP. Do something like `$userinput = rawurldecode($_GET['value']);` Some functions: [rawurldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) and [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to my `.ini` file solved the problem:

```
character-set-server = utf8  
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

When using 'utf-8 general ci' for the table fields, the values get stored properly but you will have issues when comparing strings. For example the string 'tèst' and 'test' will return true when being compared to a value whose charset and collation is utf-8 general ci..

Try to set the collation/charset to utf8_bin. This is much safer when performing string comparisons.

But remember that there is no case insensitive version to utf8_bin (ci) so you will have to convert your characters to lowercase before saving.

Regards,